# How to prevent label with empty content from collapsing?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a table with a few labels:

```
<StackPanel Margin="20">
    <Label Padding="0" Content="1" />
    <Label Padding="0" />
    <Label Padding="0" Content="3" />
    <Label Padding="0" Content="4" />
</StackPanel>
```

When label has empty content (binding returns null) it collapses. How to prevent that? If Content contains empty string everything works as intended.

Current behavior:

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

I am currently using `TargetNullValue={}` in the binding for each `Label` to prevent the control from being collapsed. But I would like a solution that allows me to use the `Label` controls in a `StackPanel` where I can use a `Style` to prevent the collapse, rather than having to set the `TargetNullValue` property in each binding for each `Label`.

Comment: Found a workaround to use `Content="{Binding Prop, TargetNullValue={}}"` for such bindings. Still looking for better solution.

Comment: What's wrong with the work-around you're using now? It seems reasonable to me. There are **many** ways to prevent the control from collapsing entirely, so as asked now your question is far too broad. Please explain why your current code doesn't work for you (including the workaround), and constrain the desired alternative enough that it doesn't take a half dozen answers to hit on the one you actually want.

Comment: I want to be apple to apply a fix to all labels with Style

Comment: _"I want to be apple [able?] to apply a fix to all labels with Style"_ -- well, you could always just explicitly set the `Label` dimensions (e.g. `Height`). Or, you could probably make an attached property that watches the binding and adds the `TargetNullValue` as needed (and the attached property could be set in the style). You could probably even just always bind `Content` to `DataContext` in the style and then do the actual binding to the source property to `DataContext`. But since you have to declare a binding for each `Label` anyway, why is it so important to put the fix in a style?

Comment: @Grant: _" the StackPanel is just coded by default to collapse any children whose content is `null`."_ -- I think it's more that the `Label` control itself simply doesn't ask for more space if its content is `null`. The `StackPanel` doesn't even care whether the control in question is a content control or not; all it's doing is giving the children what they ask for, and no more.

Comment: @Grant: yes, layout of controls in panels is controlled by the panel itself, but that is based on the measurements that the children perform. E.g. if you set the `Height` of the `Label` explicitly, the `StackPanel` won't collapse it, even if the `Content` is `null`. I.e. it's not that the panel is checking the content and basing the layout on that, it's just that the child (the `Label`) asks for a different minimum size depending on how its been configured.

Answer (score 3):

The `StackPanel` isn't going to give its children any more space than they ask for. And the `Label` control isn't going to ask for any space if it has no content and you haven't set the dimensions explicitly. Note that setting the `Height` would be sufficient for your stated purpose, but of course then the visual height of the `Label` would depend not on the content, but on that explicit setting.

I believe that the work-around you're using now is a reasonable one. It ensures that the content is never actually `null`, and so the `Label` control will always ask for a height to accommodate the given content., even if the string is empty.

You stated in a comment that you want to be able to apply this work-around via a `Style`. If you are willing to change the target property for your model binding, you can do this simply by binding the model to the `Label.DataContext` property, and then having the `Style` set the `Content` from the `DataContext`.

For example:

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO36368066NonCollapseLabel.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:p="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO36368066NonCollapseLabel"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.DataContext>
    <l:Model Text1="label 1" Text3="label 3"/>
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Window.Resources>
    <p:Style TargetType="Label">
      <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
      <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding TargetNullValue={}}"/>
    </p:Style>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <Label DataContext="{Binding Text1}"/>
    <Label DataContext="{Binding Text2}"/>
    <Label DataContext="{Binding Text3}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Sample model class just has three simple `string` properties of course:

```
class Model
{
    public string Text1 { get; set; }
    public string Text2 { get; set; }
    public string Text3 { get; set; }
}
```

Naturally, you'd use whatever model and binding was appropriate in your case.

I find the `DataContext` particularly convenient, since it makes the XAML binding syntax very simple; the default source of a binding is the `DataContext` itself, so all you need to specify is the `TargetNullValue` property. But if for some reason you don't want to store the source value in `DataContext` directly, you could use the `Tag` property instead of `DataContext` for this if you wanted. Or for that matter, you could create a whole new view model, bind *that* to the `DataContext`, and then bind to the model property as usual in the `Style`. The important thing is that the `Style` has a consistent source property to use, so the same `Style` can be applied to all your `Label` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a Grid with Rows that have their Height set to auto and MinHeight set to 10 or something around there

Comment: What if the OP wants to keep using a `StackPanel`?

Comment: You'd have to make sure the binding either returns an empty string or use the workaround that's already been implemented. A StackPanel is going to take up exactly as much space as its children require, so if the Label is bound to null than there's nothing to render. Personally I would just set the ViewModel properties to string.Empty

Answer (score 0):

```
<Label Padding="0" >
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Content" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                                <Label Padding="0" Content=" "/>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

Comment: How is this any better than using `TargetNullValue` as the OP currently is doing?

Comment: @PeterDuniho It is applicable even when Binding is not used.